# How to ignore Caps Lock state for keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: key-bindings

When Caps Lock is on, typing commands may bring surprising results, because the capital letters are used instead of what has been intended. In some modes it leads to deleting large chunks of texts, and is very irritating. On my keyboard caps lock is larger than any modifier key on the left (not sure what for).

There are ways to rebound Caps Lock, but is there a way to ignore it only in the commands? If not, what is the best way to disable the influence of Caps Lock? Maybe, there is some way to re-use on-key LED, as a bonus?

I am using Ubuntu Linux, if that matters.

Comment: I don't think Emacs can distinguish a capital letter caused by Caps Lock vs. one caused by Shift. You're best bet would be to remap Caps Lock at the OS level, e.g. using xmodmap. Remapping Caps Lock to Control is popular (and what I do) but I've seen people map it to M-x or other things.